# How to specify FontFamily if font added in another Silverlight library?

Tags: silverlight, fonts

I have created a Silverlight Class Library "HindiFont" and added a "LM.ttf" font in it (specified `BuildAction=Resource`) . Now I want to use this font in my main application "main.xap". I am aslo using Application library caching so there are *HindiFont.zip* created. So how I use the font which I have specified in *HindiFont.zip*.

I have tried below combinations but no one are working.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tDisplay" FontFamily="LM.TTF#MyName" ></TextBlock>

<TextBlock x:Name="tDisplay" FontFamily="HindiFont.dll;LM.TTF#MyName" ></TextBlock>

<TextBlock x:Name="tDisplay" FontFamily="HindiFont.zip;LM.TTF#MyName" ></TextBlock>
```

So please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: My combination's are 

<TextBlock x:Name="tDisplay" FontFamily="LM.TTF#MyName" ></TextBlock>

<TextBlock x:Name="tDisplay" FontFamily="HindiFont.dll;LM.TTF#MyName" ></TextBlock>

<TextBlock x:Name="tDisplay" FontFamily="HindiFont.zip;LM.TTF#MyName" ></TextBlock>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify it as a component and without the "LM.TTF", like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tDisplay" FontFamily="YourAppName;component/HindiFont.zip;#MyName"/>
```

If you have your fonts in a sub-directory like one named "Fonts", just use that inside:

`"/YourAppName;component/Fonts/HindiFont.zip;#MyName"`